# notify-send not showing notification when playing video

Tags: video, notify-osd, notify-send, libnotify

I have a script (which is called on keyboard button press) that instantly shows a notification with notify-send and then does some other things.

It works perfectly, except in the following cases it does not show any notifications:

- when a youtube video is playing (not necessarily in the active tab)
- when a vimeo video is playing
- when vlc player is opened

Strangely enough it does show a notification when:

- the youtube or vimeo video is paused

To clairify: The script is always called, and always produces a result. Only the notification is sometimes displayed and sometimes not displayed.
Also in all cases volume and brightness changes are shown without issues.

Ubuntu 16.04, chromium

I have installed the notifyosdconfig from ppa:gsn/grabbelkiste
and libnotify-bin from ppa:leolik/leolik

Does somebody have a clue what might be the issue here? Unfortunately I can't find anything on this issue online.
Please don't tell me this is some kind of "feature" that i can't turn off! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

This indeed seems to be a feature which can be controlled by specifying the urgency level with the option `-u --urgency=LEVEL (low,normal,critical)`.

Using `notify-send -u "critical" "notification text"` will display the notification even if video is played.
Urgency levels "low" and "normal" will not show the notification in the cases described in my original question.